# "Expected primary-expression before 'float'", chamando uma função de outra classe

Tags: c++, funções, classes

Preciso criar uma função FLorentzProton na classe Physics que receba dois vetores (v e B) e multiplique eles usando uma outra função ProdutoVetorial, da classe Mathematics, armazenando o produto no vetor F (pra depois multiplicar por outro valor - q). As classes estão definidas em .h e estão com as funções citadas declaradas nos .cpp abaixo.

*Physics.cc*

```
float Physics::FLorentzProton(double v[3], double B[3])
{   
    double q = 1.602*(10^-19);
    double F[3] = float Mathematics::ProdutoVetorial(double v[3], double B[3]); // <----- ERRO CITADO

    for(int i=0; i<=2 ;i++) 
    {
        F[i] = q*F[i];
    };
    
    return F[3];
}
```

*Mathematics.cc*

```
float Mathematics::ProdutoVetorial(double B[3], double C[3])
{
    double A[3];
    
    A[0]= (B[1]*C[2] - C[1]*B[2]);
    A[1]= (B[2]*C[0] - C[2]*B[0]);
    A[2]= (B[0]*C[1] - C[0]*B[1]);
    
    double moduloA= sqrt(pow(A[0], 2) + pow(A[1], 2) + pow(A[2], 2));
    
    return A[3];
}
```

Comment: Dê uma estudada em como referenciar um array e um elemento deste array. São coisas diferentes. Se você declara `double A[3];` os elemento desse array serão A[0], A[1] e A[2], não existe o elemento A[3], isto endereça uma área de memória fora dos limites do array. Além disso note que você não atribuiu nada a este A[3] e portanto não tem sentido este retorno além de naõ fazer nada com o cálculo atribuído a moduloA.

Comment: Um outro detalhe que vi agora é em: `double q = 1.602*(10^-19);`. O operador `^` é o  XOR (Bitwise exclusive OR) e não o operador de exponenciação, talvez você queira: `double q = 1.602E-19L;` ou ainda `double q = 1.602*pow((10, -19);`.

Comment: Poderia me explicar como referenciar esse vetor pra poder manipular ele? Ah e muito obrigado pelo aviso do exponencial, não tinha percebido.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Explicando vetor em computação não é a mesma coisa que vetor em matemática

A primeira coisa que normalmente se explica para os estudantes de exatas, é que "vetores" em linguagens de programação **não são a mesma coisa que vetores em fis/mat**, vetor em computação é uma sequência de elementos de um único 'tipo', (onde os elementos tem o mesmo tamanho em bytes na memória), podem ser de números inteiros, números de ponto flutuante, nomes, componentes de tela, páginas web, imagens, etc... mas todos os elementos do vetor tem que ter o mesmo tamanho em bytes, e também devem ocupar posições de memória em sequencia. Num caso onde double tem (normalmente) 8 bytes, double [3] ocupa 24 bytes na memória, se ele **representa** alguma grandeza é irrelevante pro compilador.

Esses dois fatores: **Mesmo tamanho individual de armazenamento e estar em sequencia** permitem que o compilador trabalhe com vetores de uma forma muito rápida, mas **contraintuitiva**: Em C/C++ quando o compilador passa um vetor de uma função para outra ele passa apenas o **endereço de memória onde está o primeiro elemento do vetor**, seja lá ele de 1, 3, 1.000 ou 1.000.000 de elementos. Dessa forma, a passagem é muito rápida sempre, pois ele não cria cópias dos elementos, ou seja, para passar um vetor de 1.000.000 de doubles, que ocupariam aproximadamente 8 Megabytes, ele passa apenas 4 bytes(em sistemas 32 bits) com a posição onde começa o vetor e nada mais. Como assim nada mais ? E o tamanho do vetor ? Bom, C/C++ **não passam o tamanho para a função chamada**.

E porque vc vê em livros ou em notas de aula algo como double[3] utilizado para armazenar um vetor(matemático) tridimensional ? Simplesmente porque uma forma muito conveniente ( em termos de processamento ) de armazenar 3 números é colocá-los em sequencia na memória.

Quando você passa um double[6] com valores 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 para uma função e essa função o recebe como parâmetro `v`, e logo abaixo você escreve um comando do como `v[5]` o compilador calcula quanto é 8(tamanho do double) x 5(posição escolhida) =
40 e soma com o valor de v (que é uma posição de memória, por exemplo 1080), como v não tem "valores" ele só representa uma posição de memória, o compilador salta imediatamente até a posição de memória v[5] que está em 1120 = 1080 + 8 * 5  e lá naquela posição de memória vai estar o valor 60 para seu cálculo.

Por isso, que quando você tenta usar v[100] num vetor que não tem esse tamanho o computador apresenta U.B. "Undefined Behaviuor", qualquer coisa pode acontecer, apresentar mensagens de "segmentation fault", "o programa trava", "tela azul", "o computador pega fogo", ou o [Cramunhão sai do seu nariz](https://accu.org/journals/overload/21/115/maudel_1857/) ( [Nasal Demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) )  ou algo assim.

2 - Calma que tem solução:

Normalmente se encapsula os vetores em estruturas

```
struct Vec3D {
   array<double, 3> v;
   Vec3D operator *( double d ) const {  // Scalar product
       return { v[0] * d, v[1] * d, v[2] * d };
   }
   Vec3D operator +( const Vec3D& o ) const { 
       return { v[0] + o.v[0], v[1] + o.v[1], v[2] + o.v[2] };
   }

   Vec3D operator *( const Vec3D& o ) const {  // Cross Product
       return { 
        v[1] * o.v[2] - v[2] * o.v[1], 
        v[2] * o.v[0] - v[0] * o.v[2], 
        v[0] * o.v[1] - v[1] * o.v[0] 
       };
   }

   double mod() const {
      return hypot( v[0], v[1], v[2] );
   }

   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Vec3D& vec) {
      return o << '[' << vec.v[0] << ',' << vec.v[1] << ',' << vec.v[2] << "]";
   }
};
```

Exemplo simples :
https://godbolt.org/z/MYsjbs

Exemplo com programação genérica C++ com vetores de muitas dimensões:
https://godbolt.org/z/ocGrbo